# Function not returning max value for each row but overall

Tags: r

I wrote a function to do 2 nested for loops to calculate the highest possible calculated value for each row. For each row I feed x into the function. However, the function then return the same value for every row.

I tried filtering only id that match the a input however, it does not seem to work.

```
        dd <- data.frame(x=c(3,4,5),id=c('A','B','C'))
  foo  <- function(x,a){
    df <- data.frame(
      "id" = character()
      ,"y" = numeric()
    )

      for(i in 1:2)
      {
        for(j in 1:2)
        {
          y<-x+i+j 
          df<- rbind(df, data.frame(
            "id" = a
            ,"y" = y
          )
          )

        }
      }
     # I tried this filtering but it still shows max calculated value from all 3 rows
     result<-df%>% 
      filter(id==a)%>%
      arrange(desc(y))%>%
      head(1)
     return(result$y)
  }

  dd%>% mutate(t=foo(dd$x, dd$id))
```

The result I'd expect is the function that returns the first row y value of each looping.

The expected result is .

> ```
>         x    id     t
>   1     3    A     7
>   2     4    B     8
>   3     5    C     9
> ```

But I got

> ```
>         x    id     t
>   1     3    A     9
>   2     4    B     9
>   3     5    C     9
> ```

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output df?

Comment: Sorry. I simplified my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

```
dd <- data.frame(x=c(3,4,5),id=c('A','B','C'))
foo  <- function(x,a){
  df <- data.frame(
    "id" = character()
    ,"y" = numeric()
  )

  for(i in 1:2)
  {
    for(j in 1:2)
    {
      y<-x+i+j 
      df<- rbind(df, data.frame(
        "id" = a
        ,"y" = y
      )
      )

    }

  }

  # Replace with group_by, filter, max
  result<-df%>% 
    group_by(id)%>%
    filter(y == max(y))
  return(result$y)
}

dd%>% mutate(t=foo(dd$x, dd$id))
```

**Output**

```
  x id t
1 3  A 7
2 4  B 8
3 5  C 9
```

**Explanation**

You just had to take care of the last `result` snippet to `group_by`  the `id` values and fetch all rows that had the max `y` for each group